# Embed string in a span tag with certain class

Tags: php

I have a string in which I want to highlight word "some":

```
$my_string = "This is some string.";
$highlight = "some";
```

And I need to wrap this word in `<span>` tags using some php function which can suit this job the best.

I am using this for my simple search on my website.

So, I would like the end result looks like this:

```
This is <span class="highlight-word">some</span> string.
```

Comment: Yes it is trivial. Take a look at [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: This surely have been answered a load of times

Comment: This can be googled very easily.

Comment: thanks guys for the function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace`](http://sk.php.net/str_replace) as mentioned in comments. So, in your case, it'd look like this:

```
$my_string = "This is some string.";
$highlight = "some";

echo str_replace($highlight, sprintf('<span class="highlight-word">%s</span>', $highlight), $my_string);
// This is <span class="highlight-word">some</span> string.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be highlighting words with a span like that. There are HTML elements specifically designed to do that see [em](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/em) and [strong](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/strong) for information on how to use them.

Your best option to achieve what you want is to wrap the PHP [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) in a wrapper function as you will probably want to do this in several places.

```
function setStrong($wordToStrong, $sentence)
{
    $strong = "<strong>$wordToStrong</strong>";
    return str_replace($wordToStrong, $strong, $sentence);
}
```

Then use like this:-

```
echo setStrong("strong", "This should be a strong word");
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that em and strong is more semantically and standart-wise correct. Btw. thanks for making a function. Ondrej was faster, however, at least vote up from me to you ;). thanks again.

Comment: Speed is not the way we judge answers on SO. You should accept the answer that works best for you regardless of how long it takes. However Ondrej's answer is correct and worthy of the tick, you should probably wrap that in a function too. The main thing is you got your answer.